# ZFS ARC dnode size > dnode max size

Tags: linux, filesystems, zfs, zfs-arc

I've copied a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/zfs/comments/fpnrn7/question_about_dnode_size_and_limits/) which asks my question and haven't been answered:

I've been tinkering with a tool to monitor ZFS usage and statistics for the last few weeks. It's encouraged me to learn a lot more about ZFS as I figure out what it's telling me. I've worked through almost all of them making adjustments only after I understand what and why I'm doing them.

One thing has me stumped, the alert that says dnode_size should not be greater than arc_dnode_limit*0.9

```
$ grep dnode /proc/spl/kstat/zfs/arcstats 
dnode_size                      4    334416720
arc_dnode_limit                 4    307463731
```

So then 334416720 ! > 276717357.9 ....err.. yikes! I'm WAY above that recommendation...

I've found a lot of good information about dnode is, specifically the [Open ZFS docs](https://openzfs.org/wiki/Documentation/DnodeSync) have been informative. But I've not found any good information about what it means that my dnode_size is so much higher than my arc_dnode_limit much less what I'm supposed to do about it.

Can someone please explain what this alert is trying to tell me? Is this actually a problem or is this just one of those "good recommendations"?

Answer (score 0):

TL,DR: So set a higher limit.

I can't answer your question as to whether it is really a problem or not, but if you're concerned that your usage is over the limit, you might consider whether your limit is artificially low, and your use case simply requires a higher limit.

This is on FreeBSD, so you'll need to read between the lines and YMMV, but with no overrides on my FreeBSD 14 laptop with 16GB RAM and a single-device, non-redundant VDEV of 460GB, FreeBSD defaults to a limit of 1,594,027,212 and my current "size/limit" ratio is .0008:

```
(No dnode setting overrides in /etc/sysctl.conf:)
$ grep dnode /etc/sysctl.conf
$ sysctl -a | egrep 'dnode_(size|limit)'
vfs.zfs.arc.dnode_limit_percent: 10
vfs.zfs.arc.dnode_limit: 0
kstat.zfs.misc.arcstats.arc_dnode_limit: 1594027212
kstat.zfs.misc.arcstats.dnode_size: 1362288
$ bc <<< "scale=4; $(sysctl -n kstat.zfs.misc.arcstats.dnode_size) / $(sysctl -n kstat.zfs.misc.arcstats.arc_dnode_limit)"
.0008
```

If I set an artificially low limit (say, 2^20) and reboot, then yes, my ratio is above the "recommendation":

```
$ grep dnode /etc/sysctl.conf
vfs.zfs.arc.dnode_limit=1048576
$ sysctl -a | egrep 'dnode_(size|limit)'
vfs.zfs.arc.dnode_limit_percent: 10
vfs.zfs.arc.dnode_limit: 1048576
kstat.zfs.misc.arcstats.arc_dnode_limit: 1048576
kstat.zfs.misc.arcstats.dnode_size: 1358248
$ bc <<< "scale=4; $(sysctl -n kstat.zfs.misc.arcstats.dnode_size) / $(sysctl -n kstat.zfs.misc.arcstats.arc_dnode_limit)"
1.2960
```

Likewise, if I feel that the default limit chosen by the OS is too low, I can set a larger limit, to achieve an even lower ratio of .0006:

```
$ grep dnode /etc/sysctl.conf
vfs.zfs.arc.dnode_limit=2147483648
$ sysctl -a | egrep 'dnode_(size|limit)'
vfs.zfs.arc.dnode_limit_percent: 10
vfs.zfs.arc.dnode_limit: 2147483648
kstat.zfs.misc.arcstats.arc_dnode_limit: 2147483648
kstat.zfs.misc.arcstats.dnode_size: 1376024
$ bc <<< "scale=4; $(sysctl -n kstat.zfs.misc.arcstats.dnode_size) / $(sysctl -n kstat.zfs.misc.arcstats.arc_dnode_limit)"
.0006
```

The vast majority of my ZFS use cases are on FreeBSD, but the OpenZFS docs suggest that:

> In some cases, the parameter must be set prior to loading the kernel
> modules or it is desired to have the parameters set automatically at
> boot time. For many distros, this can be accomplished by creating a
> file named /etc/modprobe.d/zfs.conf containing a text line for each
> module parameter using the format:

```
# change PARAMETER for workload XZY to solve problem PROBLEM_DESCRIPTION 
# changed by YOUR_NAME on DATE 
options zfs PARAMETER=VALUE
```

Try raising your dnode limit, then rebooting, and see whether your used/limit ratio improves.